# What code did Yondu break?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

In Guardians of the Galaxy Vol 2, there is a lot of talk about how Yondu broke the Ravager code.

**What code did he break?**

Comment: Ravagers don't kidnap/sell children. Yondu did.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the movie or a script to write a proper answer, but my memory is that he broke the code when he agreed to bring Ego *children* from various worlds.

Comment: The Ravager code.

Comment: Try `git blame | grep yondu`?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

He abducted kids.

We hear this "code" explained at least twice in the movie.

First, Stakar (the Ravager leader) yells it at Yondu, telling him that, for all the crimes that Ravagers commit, "we don't deal in kids!". We know that Yondu kidnapped Peter from his family at the request of Peter’s father — it appears that the Ravagers have a rule against taking this kind of job. By taking a job involving a child, Yondu broke the code.

We later learn that Yondu's crime was much worse than this. He actually abducted

> dozens of Ego's children for Ego,

for which he was paid a lot of money to convince him to violate the code so blatantly. He only stopped when he picked up Peter and decided not to return him to his father as demanded. In *Guardians of the Galaxy* we learn that Yondu broke his contract with Peter's father and instead raised him as a Ravager; in *Guardians of the Galaxy Vol 2* we finally learn the real reason why. Unfortunately, by then it was already too late, he had been exiled.

Comment: Interestingly, the Ravager code stresses ***kids*** which indicates to me that they don't have a problem with abduction/transport of adults for illegal purposes.  In short, the Ravagers seem like they'd be fine with transporting slaves, but not child slaves.  It's a fine line, but Yondu crosses it when he abducts children.

Comment: Also, it's hard to draw the line between bounty hunting (which everyone seems to be into) and transportation for slavery, so drawing the line at kids seems like a reasonable place (in universe).

Comment: I don't understand though, why he was punished so long after the act. Seems like he'd been a Ravager, running around with Quill for nearly 20 years and it's only during GotG2 that he gets banned?