# Why did Yondu not deliver Peter?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

During the movie, we learned that Ego tried to reproduce the Celestial gene by having a lot of children and then having them delivered to him. I am not sure if Yondu was contracted for all of them but he definitely delivered at least a few of them since he broke the ravager code and got banned for dealing in kids.

My question is: **why did he stop with Peter?** Was Peter the last one on the contract or did he keep on delivering some but just not Peter?

Also, why didn't Ego seek out Yondu to get his kid back?

I don't think this was touched on in the movie. This was slightly mentioned here ([What code did Yondu break?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/158918/what-code-did-yondu-break)) but that is not answering my question.

I think Yondu said it was because he could get to places where the Ravagers could not since he was a kid but that would have been true with all the others kids he abducted for Ego.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Michael Rooker (Yondu) says the following in an interview with comicbook.com

> "It was a gig," Rooker said. "I was to pick up the kid and bring him to Ego, right? And I decided not to because I find out things about him that I don't really agree with and I don't like. Hence, my opinion of him as being a jackass! So, I keep the little guy and I like him. He's got spunk."
>   <sub>[Comicbook.com - Michael Rooker Interview](http://comicbook.com/marvel/2017/04/26/michael-rooker-yondu-guardians-of-the-galaxy-vol-2-/)</sub>

That seems to suggest it could've been any child that Yondu changed his mind on, it just so happens to be Peter. There's no particular reason of Peter being special or anything of the like. It was just when Yondu decided Ego was a dodgy business partner.

Bear in mind, [this question covers whether or not Yondu was the only one delivering mini-Egos](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160698/did-anyone-else-transport-egos-children) and establishes that others could've been delivering Ego's kids too. Meaning Peter may have been the last one picked up by Yondu but not necessarily the last of Ego's children that were picked up.

Comment: Hmm, so basically, it just good timing that Peter was last "on the list", that Yondu learned what Ego was doing around that time, etc... A bit disappointing but OK. I will wait to see if there are other answers and I will chose yours after

Comment: He may not have been the **last** but he was the last on that got picked up

Comment: @Edlothiad Small correction, last one that got picked up by Yondu; I'm not sure if we know but someone else could have gone out to pick the others up.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder - True, but then why would he have spent so long searching for Peter?

Comment: @Edlothiad Probably after he heard about him holding onto the infinity stone for so long. Also it seems he was hunting all his children so the whole time spent hunting Peter could have been interspersed with him hunting others.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder These are both great points! I'll add them in.

Comment: @TheLethalCoder Yeah, thanks for mentioning this. Everything seems to be less a matter of coincidences this way

Comment: It's still pretty major that it was Peter quill, it just that that's the character to progress the story. People need to realise more often that a lot of things happen purely to progress the story, or to fit the story

Comment: @Edlothiad Exactly it was a writers coincidence that it was Peter.

Answer (score 15):

Yondu did not deliver Peter because he found out what happend to the other children:

> Starlord: "Guess I should be glad I was a skinny kid, otherwise you would've delivered me to this maniac."
>
> Yondu: "You still reckon that's the reason I kept you around you idiot?"
>
> S: "That's what you told me you old doofus."
>
> Y: "Well once I figured out what happened to those other kids, I wasn't just gonna hand you over."
>
> S: "You said you were gonna eat me."
>
> Y: "That was being funny."
>
> S: "Not to me."

Comment: Is this from memory or from an actual script?

Comment: remembered the dialogue and looked it up, but could not find an official script, just this on this [wiki](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Yondu_Udonta/Quote)