# Why did Ego not collect his children himself?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2, celestials

Through the movie we come to learn that Ego had hired Yondu to pick up his children to deliver them to him. We also know that he was paying Yondu quite a lot for each job as well. [When Yondu finds out what happened to the others](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160521/why-did-yondu-not-deliver-peter) he stops delivering them and this just so happens to have been Peter.

It appears Ego has no use for money, that I can think of, but surely the risk of someone not delivering/failing could have been avoided if he had collected them himself. Like he ended up having to do with Peter.

Is there any reason why Ego did not pick his children up himself?

Comment: If the answer to this is the same as your other question it will be closed as a duplicate, which it right now seems to be.

Comment: @Edlothiad Do you mean [Did anyone else transport Ego's children](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/160698/58193)? I don't think the answer is the same, the answers may use the same quote but they both draw different interpretations of it. In this case I believe the answer to be drawing a stretched interpretation.

Comment: I was going to ask this question as well. I wonder if it has anything to do with Ego saying something like "If I went back to Earth, I knew I'd never be able to leave".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No direct answer is given in the movie, but Ego says,

> I had Yondu deliver **some of them** to me.

(Emphasis added)

So, it is entirely possible that he *did* collect some of his children, and sent Yondu to pick up others. Or, after so many failures, he may have been spending his time making more children. However, in Peter's case, Ego does give a reason: he says that it would have been too painful to return to Earth, knowing that Meredith Quill was dead. That is probably especially true, given that

> Ego gave her the cancer that killed her.

and despite his other lies, it seems that Ego really did love her.

Comment: That sentence could mean anything though: "Only some of all my kids"; "Some other people delivered others"; "I found some of them" etc.

Comment: I see your point just seems a bit of a stretch with the most likely answer on the interpretation to be "I had other people deliver the rest of them".

Answer (score 9):

Uh, sheer numbers and time.

Ego has to return to his home planet from time to time in order to replenish his power, and he's probably got to be there to build and perhaps maintain his planet.

We don't know how many women Ego slept with and where they were in the galaxy relative to his home base. We also don't know that he stopped sleeping with women to continue this after he made Peter.

My impression was that Ego had so many that Yondu not coming back with Peter wasn't something that deeply troubled him, and he had a lot of other kids coming in from different sources or he went and got the closer ones himself (see KSmarts answer--really do think other folks were ferrying them in for Ego). Only once he heard about the Infinity Stone, did Ego decide to look, and put together that it had to be Peter. If he investigated at all, Peter Quill's name would be in any report regarding this. And Ego would know who that is, just from the last name.

**Basically, with all the boning, the breaking in of children, the maintaining of his planet and power, dude just didn't have the time to pick up all his kids when they got "ripe."** Earth may be geographically further away than some other planets, so it's possible Ego picked some of his own kids up.

Comment: The majority of this answer seems to be answering a different question... https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160698/did-anyone-else-transport-egos-children

Comment: @TheLethalCoder The other question has bearing on this one, sure, but the answer to that one as far as I am concerned would be different--related, but different. The answer to this one is that he likely did pick some of his own up. The answer to the other would bring in the emotions he felt about P's mom. Since Peter is the only concrete example and Ego actually did pick him up, I cited it.

Comment: Yes, I too have very little time on my hands, due to boning ;-)