# Did anyone else transport Ego's children?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-2

Throughout the movie we learn that Ego had hired Yondu in the past to deliver some of his children to him. We also learn that Yondu eventually stops delivering the children at some point in time, with Peter happening to be the last one he picks up.

At this point, or before Yondu, do we know whether anyone else was hired to deliver the children to Ego?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The movie never says anything outright about other people abducting Ego's children, but I think it would be almost impossible for Yondu to have done it by himself.

When Nebula and Gamora uncover the skeletons of Ego's children, the *sheer number* of them is staggering. It's an entire chamber of Ego's subsurface caverns packed head-to-toe with them.

Consider what had to have happened here:

- Ego waits for one of his children to reach a certain age (~7 Earth years, though it may depend on their species).
- Ego pays Yondu to go get the child and return it to him.
- Ego then tries to teach the child to use his Celestial powers, eventually deciding they didn't have any.
- Ego kills that child, then waits for the next one to grow up and repeats.

This means that Yondu was bringing children one at a time to Ego, and there was at least some delay in between trips. It also means that Yondu was continually dropping off children on Ego's surface and never seeing them again. He eventually figured out on his own what was happening, probably based on how shady the whole situation was.

Given how many times this must have happened, I'm not sure Yondu was even *alive* long enough to make that many trips before he quit doing it. And even if he was, I can't imagine him making it over and over again enough times to pack a cave *full* of corpses *before* catching on that something was amiss.

So, if for no other reason than to keep Yondu's intelligence and sanity intact, I think we have to assume there were other couriers before and/or after him.

Comment: Yeah when you made your comment on the OP it made me think pretty much what you've wrote here anyway. This is probably the best answer we'll get on this, pending any new information.

Comment: This is the best answer to this specific question.

Comment: Also I get the impression this was going on for *thousands or millions of years*

Comment: Do we know for sure it was sequential like this? I figure Ego could've afforded to have at least one visit a year -- he could easily enough determine if each child is suitable, dispose of the ones that aren't, clean up, and move on inside of a year. (Even then I totally agree it's way more than Yondu could've done all on his own.)

Comment: @doppelgreener There is the entire "go to planet, learn about it, seduce a member of the species, keep track of child well enough to be able to hire someone to get the child back" bit.  Then be back on the planet enough to train up previous children to see if they have the ability required.

Comment: As it is unclear exactly how many children Yondu transported ("some"), it could have been a small number. As such, is it not possible that over so many years, and multiple other transporters, Ego simply allowed these children to live out their mortal lives?

Comment: Ego's own comments about those children, combined with his general disregard for other beings (e.g. Peter's mother), plus the fact that he hid the bodies deep underground, all "strongly suggest" that he got rid of those children when they were deemed "useless". I don't think he outright says "I killed them" but the implication is very clear.

Answer (score 15):

Ego says the following (emphasis mine):

> I had Yondu deliver **some of them** to me. It broke the Ravager code, but I compensated him generously.

This could mean that Yondu was the only one collecting them and that Ego only had some of the children delivered, but considering how desperate Ego was to get a second Celestial for his plan, I think it's more likely that he had all the children he begat delivered to him, but Yondu only got some of them, the rest being collected by other people, presumably other Ravagers of loose morals.

Comment: Why presume other Ravegers?

Comment: It's admittedly speculation, but I can't imagine who else would be even remotely willing and capable of transporting children all across the Galaxy.