# Why did Yondu abduct Quill and then raise him as his son?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1

Within MCU canon, what was Yondu's motivation to travel to Earth, only abduct Quill, and then raise him as his son?

It seemed to me that Yondu and his crew of Ravagers had more rewarding things to do if they were going to travel all the way to Earth, and had more rewarding uses for Quill than making him an adopted son. Or am I missing something?

Comment: "Am I missing something?" - The second movie

Comment: @Jack the ending of the first movie as well.

Answer (score 3):

This is revealed in the second Guardians of the Galaxy movie:

> Peter Quill is actually the son of Ego, the living planet, who hired Yondu to go fetch him. Yondu gets cold feet and decides not to deliver Quill. Since he has nothing better to do with Quill, he keeps him as part of the crew. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guardians_of_the_Galaxy_Vol._2#Plot, and also see [Why did Yondu not deliver Peter?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/160521/) for why he didn't follow through with the delivery.

Comment: That's what doesn't quite make sense to me. Yondu doesn't seem the caring type; the fact that he abducted Quill in the first place makes Quill more of a commodity to Yondu than anything else, and as a child, not very useful as crew. Selling Quill off as a slave (or perhaps cannibalizing him) seemed to me more in line with Yondu's character than effectively adopting him.

Comment: @AnthonyX Yondu is a lot less nasty than he pretends to be.

Comment: Seemed pretty cold and ruthless when he got to work with that whistle-controlled dart thing.